# Batch Script Search & Delete all folders that match name "*Cache*" but leave out certain paths from traversal

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, search, cmd, traversal

As I asked in Q-title, how can I traverse the whole `%SYSTEMDRIVE%` root folder for any directory that contains `*Cache*` in it's name and fully purge that directory inside-out but leave out certain paths from such traverse-delete, such as `%APPDATA%\npm` ?

I have the following command for traversing and deleting all folders containing `Cache`(case-insensitive) in their name and delete those completely:

```
pushd "%SYSTEMDRIVE%"
for /d /r %%a in ("*Cache*") do if exist "%%a" ( echo "%%a" & rd /s /q "%%a" )
popd
```

But I want to skip looking into `%APPDATA%\npm` completely, how can I achieve that ?

**Note:** OS: Windows 10 64Bit

Comment: Do you want to purge the directory in other words clean it out, or remove the directory as well?

Comment: Preferably remove the directory as well, so full clean first it's contents and then the folder itself

Comment: ok, I will be careful with that though. You also have `%localappdata%` and other directories which can contain `__cache__` directories which are required for the application to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
pushd "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\"
for /d /r %%a in ("*cache*") do if exist "%%a" ECHO "%%a"|FINDSTR /i /L /c:"%appdata%\npm\" >NUL&IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo delete "%%a") ELSE (echo skip "%%a")
POPD
GOTO :EOF
```

First issue : you need to `pushd` to the root directory of your drive, otherwise you will select the currently-logged directory on that drive.

Then simply `echo` the directoryname found to `findstr` to see whether that name contains the directoryname to exclude. The name needs to be quoted to allow for names containing `&`. `Findstr` looks for a `/i` case-**I**nsensitive  `/L` **L**iteral match to the constant-string contained in `appdata`. with the subdirectotyname appended, and a backslash appended to *that* so that it does **not** match against "...\npmnotamatch".

If `findstr` finds a match, `errorlevel` is set to `0` so the directory should be skipped, else delete.

Be very, very careful. Please see [Caution regarding directorynames](https://superuser.com/a/931002/229204)

Comment: One question though, can I use any wildcard like `*` in this `/c:` clause, like if I want to ignore any full path that contains `node_modules` any position in the path, like `"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\cache" `, just for knowledge, if it's not too much off-topic ?

Comment: You should read `findstr /?` from the prompt (or `anycommand /?` for documentation on any command (sometimes it's a little cryptic). You can add other exclusions to the list by adding `/c:"string to ignore"` elements, or you can use the `/g:filename` option to read the list of target strings (which are here being used as exclusions) from a file.